# Send Video in Email Swift

Tags: swift, email, video, send

I want to send a video in email but it does not work. i convert the video url to nsdata end then give it the email addAttachmentDat. Thanks for Help

```
       let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()

    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: shareurl!) {

        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
        picker.setSubject("#Email")
        picker.setMessageBody("Email Send", isHTML: true)
        picker.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "wav", fileName: "shareurl.wav")
    }

    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not work"?

Comment: if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: shareurl!) {} on this line it stops to run it don´t show the email controller. the Problem is in this line but i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that it's dying on `if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: shareurl!)` then it's most likely because `shareurl` is null. You always need to make sure your variable isn't null before putting a `!` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Or there could be memory problem, when file is large. It happened to me with movie file. In that case you will find "Received memory warning" in console window.